# Why VS Code context menu showing single item

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, contextmenu

In `VS Code`, context menu started showing single item. I don't know how this happened. Before that it was showing 4 to 5 items but now it's only showing one.

You can see through this image as well. It should show all the menu items because current menu has 4 to 5 items.

[image]

Comment: Just drag the lower border of that suggestion box down.

Comment: @Mark Thank you. It resolved.